# Truffle npm install problem on my windows 10

Tags: npm, truffle

I have some problem when installing truffle. I used this instruction:

```
npm install -g truffle
```

But I'm always met with this error like below screen:

[image]

Several times I've tried, but the result was same.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve that error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afVLR.png

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. My friends installed truffle easily on his computer, but now I don't  understand that library can't be installed on my computer

Comment: @Sun-Mount - regarding the other comment asking for the error message in text form: this means editing your question to include the actual error message, as properly-formatted text, instead of a screenshot of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.